# What's the difference between a wrapper, a bridge and a mediator?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, wrapper, bridge, mediator

I'm reviewing slides for my course in software architecture, and supposedly there's a difference between the three terms. Although the slides attempt to adress the differences, I don't quite "get" it. It would be nice if someone could help clarify the differences, strengths and weaknesses of the three.

Comment: Cross-posted at about the same time to [cs.stackexchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2284/82).

Answer (score 4):

**Wrapper is also called Adapter**:

Permits classes with disparate interfaces to work together by
creating a common object by which they may communicate
and interact.

Use When:

- A class to be used doesn’t meet interface requirements.
- Complex conditions tie object behavior to its state.
- Transitions between states need to be explicit.

---

**Bridge:**

Defines an abstract object structure independently of the
implementation object structure in order to limit coupling.

Use When:

- Abstractions and implementations should not be bound at compile time.
- Changes in the implementation of an abstraction should have no impact on clients.
- Implementation details should be hidden from the client.

---

**Mediator:**

Allows loose coupling by encapsulating the way disparate sets of
objects interact and communicate with each other. Allows for the
actions of each object set to vary independently of one another.

Use When:

- Communication between sets of objects is well defined and complex.
- Too many relationships exist and common point of control or communication is needed.